# Rest API calls in REACT

Tags: reactjs

I am working on existing code base for a react application. I am new to React and the developer who wrote this left.
In my current code base "request-promise-native" is pass from one component to another component using props. I don't get this. Why not just import it again in every component?

**App.tsx**

```
import rp from 'request-promise-native';

const App: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" render={(props) => <Main {...props} rp={rp} />}></Route>
        </Router>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation of `https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise` it appears this is completely pointless and you are correct about imports.